# Why null value in the table getting error while using lead function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, lead

I am getting this error - **Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.**

I have data coming from a table and I need only two values from the table where I filter only the number (no alphanumeric so used the isnumeric(covrg_cd)=1). The input data looks like the first picture. The Row 1 will always be null and in other other rows, there may or may not be data. However, because row 1 is always null, the lead function is throwing this error: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric, but the rate column is always in nvarchar.  I am using LEAD function in SQL to get the paybandfrom & paybandto using the Rate from Input table and using row_number() to get the tier value.
**Input table**

[image]

**out put must be like this..**
[image]

I have my query like this

```
SELECT a.payband , a.[from] as pybdnfrom, (RIGHT('00000000000000000000' + CAST(A.[TO] AS VARCHAR),20)) AS pybndto , a.tier 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.RATE as payband, A.RATE as [from], CASE WHEN TIER <> 4 THEN A.[TO] ELSE 100000000.000 END AS [to],  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RATE) AS TIER
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT A.RATE, LEAD(SUM((CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,3), (A.RATE)))-0.010)) OVER(ORDER BY A.RATE)  AS [TO], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.RATE) AS TIER     
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT BN_RATE_KEY02 as RATE, COVRG_CD AS COVERAGE 
      from #tmppsRateCost 
      WHERE ISNUMERIC(COVRG_CD) = 1 AND COVRG_CD = '1')A GROUP BY A.RATE)A)A 
ORDER BY 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we assume that this is T-SQL (MS SqlServer)?

Comment: yes, it is T-SQL

Comment: And what is that "**strong text**" near the end of your query?

Comment: thanks for the note, its by mistake, I edited and updated

Comment: I don't follow "but the data will be there and required data." What does this mean?

Comment: Also why are you doing SUM anywhere? It doesn't seem like your desired results show any SUM happening. Can you please create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019 with create table, sample data in the form of inserts, and real desired results in text instead of a screenshot?

Comment: [I think this is what you're after](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f09181bab1ccd233c03102ecd87a822) but, without table structure, sample data, and proper desired results, I've made a lot of assumptions based only on your (non-working) query. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [this](https://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/).

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I did test your code but I'm getting an Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric. How do I share the data csv file with you? It's quite a long file--more than 500 rows. Thank you once again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Surely you can reproduce the problem with less than 500 rows? Get just enough data to cause the problem into a #temp table, and then create a fiddle with just those rows as inserts, and we can go from there. No I don't want to download a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the '' cannot be parsed as a number. It's not related to the LEAD.
If you want to keep that approach you can modify your query in this way (I just commented the parts I replaced):

```
SELECT a.payband
    ,a.[from] AS pybdnfrom
    --,(RIGHT('00000000000000000000' + CAST(A.[TO] AS VARCHAR), 20)) AS pybndto
    ,CASE WHEN payband = '' THEN '' ELSE (RIGHT('00000000000000000000' + CAST(A.[TO] AS VARCHAR), 20)) END AS pybndto
    ,a.tier
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.RATE AS payband
        ,A.RATE AS [from]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN TIER <> 5
                THEN A.[TO]
            ELSE 100000000.000
            END AS [to]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY RATE
            ) AS TIER
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT A.RATE
            --,LEAD(SUM((CONVERT(NUMERIC(20, 3), (A.RATE))) - 0.010)) OVER (
            ,LEAD(SUM((CONVERT(NUMERIC(20, 3), (CASE WHEN A.RATE = '' THEN '0.010' ELSE A.RATE END))) - 0.010)) OVER (
                ORDER BY A.RATE
                ) AS [TO]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY A.RATE
                ) AS TIER
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT BN_RATE_KEY02 AS RATE
                ,COVRG_CD AS COVERAGE
            FROM #tmppsRateCost
            WHERE ISNUMERIC(COVRG_CD) = 1
                AND COVRG_CD = '1'
            ) A
        GROUP BY A.RATE
        ) A
    ) A

ORDER BY 1
```

Anyway I guess you might have a cleaner approach just by removing the empty line in the initial table.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `ISNUMERIC()` and use `TRY_CONVERT()` insert of `CONVERT()`.  In this condition:

```
              WHERE ISNUMERIC(COVRG_CD) = 1 AND COVRG_CD = '1'
```

The `ISNUMERIC()` is just unneeded because you have an exact string comparison.

```
SELECT a.payband , a.[from] as pybdnfrom,
         (RIGHT('00000000000000000000' + CAST(A.[TO] AS VARCHAR),20)) AS pybndto ,
      a.tier 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.RATE as payband, A.RATE as [from],
             CASE WHEN TIER <> 4 THEN A.[TO] ELSE 100000000.000 END AS [to],  
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RATE) AS TIER
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.RATE,
                   LEAD(SUM((TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,3), (A.RATE)))-0.010)) OVER (ORDER BY A.RATE)  AS [TO], 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.RATE) AS TIER     
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT BN_RATE_KEY02 as RATE, COVRG_CD AS COVERAGE 
                  FROM #tmppsRateCost 
                  WHERE COVRG_CD = '1'
                 )A
            GROUP BY A.RATE
           ) A
      ) A 
ORDER BY 1;
```